# How to mount the android img file under linux?

Tags: android, rom

Recently, I'm interest in the android rom, I want to change and rebuild them.
So, I did some test on my XOOM, it's very easy to flash something into the machine.
I got some ROM from MOTOROLA (http://developer.motorola.com/products/software/),
they are some img file, and I want to know what's inside, I hope to unpack them.

I tried the **unyaffs**, it said `broken img file`.
I try to mount them, it works great on the system.img, and I can get the file inside.

When I want to mount userdata.img by `mount -o loop userdata.img /mnt/userdata` (the same as `system.img`), it tells me `mount: you must specify the filesystem type` so I try the `mount -t ext2 -o loop userdata.img /mnt/userdata`, it said `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on...`

So, how to get the file from the inside of `userdata.img`?

Comment: I have tried other file system, it return the same error.

Comment: system.img:   Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4-0000-675f-946fc0f9f25b (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files)

Comment: I use file to get the img info as above.

Comment: Voting for reopen, since this is about a specific format and a specific project, and equivalent to any other howto question on the website. Open dupe at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137795/how-to-mount-aosp-img-files

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See the answer at: http://omappedia.org/wiki/Android_eMMC_Booting#Modifying_.IMG_Files

First you need to "uncompress" `userdata.img` with `simg2img`, then you can mount it via the loop device.

Comment: I have found that page has everything needed: (including source ready to be built). Worked on Nexus 4 images. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1081239

Comment: also mentioned on a github page https://github.com/EpicAOSP/make_ext4/blob/master/README

Answer (score 30):

I have found a simple solution: [http://andwise.net/?p=403](https://web.archive.org/web/20141021103926/http://andwise.net/?p=403)

### Quote

(with slight adjustments for better readability)

---

> This is for all who want to unpack and modify the original *system.img* that you can flash using recovery.
>   *system.img* (which you get from the google factory images for example) represents a sparse ext4 loop mounted file system.
>   It is mounted into */system* of your device. Note that this tutorial is for ext4 file system. You may have system image which is yaffs2, for example.
>
> The way it is mounted on Galaxy Nexus:

```
/dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.0/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

> Prerequisites:
>
> - Linux box or virtual machine
> - simg2img and make_ext4fs binaries, which can be downloaded from the linux package *android-tools-fsutils*
>
> Procedure:
>
> Place your *system.img* and the 2 binaries in one directory, and make sure the binaries have exec permission.
>
> Part 1 – mount the file-system

```
mkdir sys
./simg2img system.img sys.raw
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop sys.raw sys/
```

> Then you have your system partition mounted in ‘sys/’ and you can modify whatever you want in ‘sys/’. For example de-odex apks and framework jars.
>
> Part 2 – create a new flashable system image

```
sudo ./make_ext4fs -s -l 512M -a system new.img sys/
sudo umount sys
rm -fr sys
```

> Now you can simply type:

```
fastboot flash system new.img
```

---

Comment: `simg2img` (and `make_ext4fs`) is also available in the `android-tools-fsutils` package on Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, using this method I've encountered an error saying "Invalid sparse file format at header magi
Failed to read sparse file"

Comment: After installing `android-tools-fsutils`, I didn't need to copy `simg2img` and `make_ext4fs` to the same directory as `system.img`. They're both in my PATH and work fine from there.

Answer (score 2):

In Android file system, "system.img" and "userdata.img" are VMS Alpha executable. "system.img" and "userdata.img" have the contents of /system and /data directory on root file system. They are mapped on NAND devices with yaffs2 file system. Now, yaffs2 image file can not be mounted on linux PC. If you can, maybe you got some rom that not packed in yaffs2 file system. You can check those rom file by execute the command:

```
file <system.img/userdata.img>
```

If it show "VMS Alpha executable" then you can use "unyaffs" to extract it.

Comment: Possibly true for Samsung devices, but not for Nexus devices.

Comment: Type 'adb shell mount' to check what filesystems the Android device thinks these .img files are: I wasted time trying to unyaff an ext4 image...

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the File Explorer in DDMS (Eclipse SDK), you can see the whole file system there and download/upload files to the desired place. That way you don't have to mount and deal with images. Just remember to set your device as USB debuggable (from Developer Tools)

Answer (score -2):

I have found that Furius ISO mount works best for me. I am using a Debian based distro Knoppix. I use this to Open `system.img` files all the time.

Furius ISO mount: `https://packages.debian.org/sid/otherosfs/furiusisomount`

"When I want to mount userdata.img by mount -o loop userdata.img /mnt/userdata (the same as system.img), it tells me mount: you must specify the filesystem type so I try the mount -t ext2 -o loop userdata.img /mnt/userdata, it said mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on...

So, how to get the file from the inside of userdata.img?"
To load `.img` files you have to select loop and load the `.img` [Select loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDBMd.png)

Next you select mount
[Select mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzCNq.png)

Furius ISO mount handles all the other options loading the `.img` file to your /home/dir.