# How to mount AOSP .img files?

Tags: android, android-source

I generate ***.img**  by building **AOSP**.

Like **ramdisk.img,boot.img** etc.

I want to **mount** this file. I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/furiusisomount/

Comment: using furiusisomount , i cannot find any file in mount point directory

Comment: In that case http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65316

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot mount `boot.img` file. However you can unpack it's ramdisk.

The `boot.img` file contains:

- ramdisk
- zImage (kernel binary)
- dt.img (device tree)

There is an excellent open source project: [`mkbootimg_tools` at GitHub](https://github.com/xiaolu/mkbootimg_tools). You can use it to split the `boot.img` file and unpack the ramdisk.

Unpack boot.img:

```
mkbootimg_tools/mkboot boot.img boot_unpacked
```

To unpack system.img you first need to understand what kind of partition is it:
run: 
`file system.img`

If you get 'Android sparse image', then you have a sparse image, meaning you need to un-sparse it before mounting:
`simg2img system.img system_raw.img`

Then you can mount system_raw.img simply by running:
sudo mount system_raw.img /mnt/android_sys

Comment: No. mkbootimg_tools works only for boot.img and recovery.img.

Comment: Than for other images??

Answer (score 1):

**`simg2img`**

Some Android images are compressed by default for some builds. This is the case for example of the HiKey960 build with `lunch hikey960-eng`, but not for emulator builds e.g. with `lunch aosp_x86_64-eng`.

You must first use`simg2img` to decompress them:

```
simg2img system.img out.img
sudo losetup --show -f -P out.img
sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/loop0
```

`simg2img` lives under `./out/host/linux-x86/bin/simg2img`, and gets added automatically to PATH by `lunch`.

Note however that this is not the case for all the images, e.g. `boot.img`.

If you skip `simg2img`, you get the error:

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/loop3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/loop3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

when trying to mount.

It appears that the compressed format is something that fastboot can understand.

Also mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9675784/895245

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04 host, at branch `repo init -b android-8.1.0_r1`.

Comment: This is a bit confused as to the contents.   As the existing answer points out, boot.img is not a filesystem image, but rather a combination of a kernel, a squashfs, and typically some other data.  Ordinary gzip and squashfs tools work on the filesystem portion.   What fastboot needs to "interpret" is not that, but things like the system.img which are in "sparse" form.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks for feedback. I now learned that this is not the case for all .img. I had tested it with `system.img` and others, but not with `boot.img`.